# HTTP 500 - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I tried reading many topics but I found no answer.
Plz, some illuminated soul can help me?

[image: error]

The code are just 3 files, a very simple query using jsp.

- NetBeans 8.1
- Maven Web Application
- Java EE 7 WEB
- GlassFish 4.1.1
- Source/Binary 1.8

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Exercício 01 JDBC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Listagem de Usuário:</h1>
        <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="App">
            <P> Clique em <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="LISTAR"> 
                para obter a relação do nome do primeiro usuário.</p>
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.java**

```
package br.com.yonathan.faculdades.jdbc;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;

@WebServlet(name = "App", urlPatterns = {"/App"})
public class App extends HttpServlet {

    private Connection con;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@yyy.inf.poa.ifrs.edu.br:1521:XE";
        final String us = "xxx";
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, us, us);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String sql = "SELECT nome FROM JDBC_USUARIO where ROWNUM = 1";
        String saida = "";
        try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {

            while (rs.next()) {

                saida = rs.getString(1);

            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        request.setAttribute("resultado", saida);

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("resposta.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

**resposta.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Servlet Exibe Resultado</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JDBC Connection</h1>
        <h2>Primeiro nome cadastrado:</h2>
        ${resultado}.
    </body>
</html>
```

The user and passwd are the same.
I really tried to fix before posting.

Comment: Well, do you have the oracle JDBC driver installed and in a lib folder of your project?

Comment: maven project.
i tried just java web with jar driver, same error.

Comment: looking at your error, it seems like application not able to find the oracle driver jar. Please check whether driver jar is available in your war file in path - "application/WEB-INF/lib".

Comment: http://s18.postimg.org/dkzohqbft/oracle_2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file "**pom.xml**" into **Project Files**, I had to add:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and it works.
I have no idea why doesn't works from the beginning. It's a Maven project, but I had to include "manually" this things and then when I click to run he download the missing driver and seems working well until now.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Look for `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar` in your oracle install and put that file into `WEB-INF/lib`. Then restart tomcat and try again.